# django listview filter & get value templates

Tags: django, listview, filter

I made a list of events registered today in the inventory template, and I would like to show the total rating of the events(registered today).

I called it from the template by making the sum of the scores a function, but it is not visible. Does anyone know?

**views.py**

```
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
   model = Event
   template_name = 'cal/calendar.html'

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    return Event.objects.all().filter(start_time__date=date.today())

def filter_event_rating_sum(self):
    filtered_event = Event.objects.all().filter(start_time__date=date.today())
    sum_rating = 0
    for each_event in filtered_event:
        sum_rating += each_event.rating
    return sum_rating

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
    cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
    # issue self.request.user 
    html_cal = cal.formatmonth(self.request.user, withyear=True)
    context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
    context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
    context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
    return context
```

**templates.html**

```
    <p class="today">Today</p>

    {% for list in object_list %}
        <div class="today_list_item">
            <span>{{ list.title }}</span>
            <span class="each_rating">{{ list.rating }}</span>

        </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <p class="total">TOTAL</p>

    {{ sum_rating }}
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, blank = True)
    # default = timezone.now,
    profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='event',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, default='enter your value')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}/ {}/ {}'.format(self.id, self.title, self.start_time, self.rating)
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation in your code, or maybe it's just like that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can only use those variables which are in the dictionary returned by  get_context_data function. Add this code in get_context_data function like this

```
queryset['sum_rating'] = self.filter_event_rating_sum()
```

Comment: thank you. i changed view file like that, and in template i wrote         
<p>{{ sum_rating }}</p>
 but the number doesn't show..

Comment: are the functions defined inside the class or outside the class. Print anything inside the get_context_data function and check it isgetting called or not.

Comment: thank you for comment. but it is not called. i think because i have another get_context_data that shows calendar. so it doesn't work.